# C# how to create the following syntax Method(param => { params.xxx })?

Tags: c#

In a code example I've seen the following code:

```
SomeClass.Columns(columns => {
        columns.Add()
            .Text("Product")
            .Value("123");

        columns.Add()
            .Text("Amount")
            .Value("456");
})
```

Now I was wondering what the requirements are to create this kind of structure

Where `columns` is a collection of `Column` objects and
`.Text` and `.Value` are methods on the `Column` object that return the `Object` again (to create the fluent syntax).

The `columns.Add()` would return a `new Column()` object

What would be the parameter(s) in the method in the SomeClass.Columns(???)?
Does this syntax have a specific name that I can research?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Yes there is fluent syntax in my example but that was not my question, sorry that I was not clear.

The question is howI make to following:

```
SomeClass.Columns(columns => { ... })
```

So how does the parameter in the method Columns look?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it just fluent syntax? ...

Comment: I think you're probably looking for [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and/or [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Columns is a method, not a property. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need a collection type that creates a new instance and returns it when called "Add":

```
interface IList<T>
{
    T Add();
}
```

Then there is the fluent Column class:

```
class Column
{
    public Column Text(string text)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return this;
    }

    public Column Value(string value)
    {
        // Do stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then there is SomeClass which allows the user to give an action to perform on the "collection":

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static IList<Column> localList;

    public static void Columns(Action<IList<Column>> action)
    {
        // Perform action using localList as parameter
        action(localList);
    }
}
```

This would satisfy the syntax of:

```
SomeClass.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add()
        .Text("Product")
        .Value("123");

    columns.Add()
        .Text("Amount")
        .Value("456");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete example.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, `Columns` is accepting something like `Action<ColumnCollection>`. That is, you pass it a delegate/lambda, it promises to call that lambda, passing *in* whatever `columns` is going to be, and then within your lambda/delegate you can manipulate the collection.

Comment: This seems to be the answer, I will try and implement this in my code (and in a few minutes upvote this answer if it is by then still the best answer). Thank you

Comment: Not Func<ColumnCollection, ColumnCollection>? passing in columns and return the new collection constructed from the Add(), Text() and Value() methods

Comment: @Hyarus - the lambda shown in the question is clearly `void`. It's not single line and there's no `return`. `Add` etc. are clearly manipulating some mutable type.

Comment: @Hyarus - of course, `Columns` itself is free to have a `ColumnCollection` return type if that's appropriate for a fluent interface but I'd have thought it more likely to return whatever `SomeClass` is instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static class SomeClass
{
    public object void Columns(Func<Foo,object> action)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}


public class Foo
{

    public Foo Add()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public Foo Value(object value)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public Foo Text(string text)
    {
        return this;
    }

}
```

use like this:

```
 SomeClass.Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Add().Text("SomeText");
            columns.Add().Value("SomeValue");

            return columns;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a Fluent interface or a Fluent method. The way it works is that `.Add()`, `.Text()` and `.Value()` all return the same object afterwards that they're performing operations on as their return value. This is what allows operations to be chained in this way. `Columns` is simply returning an enumerable of these exact same objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Higher-order functions. In c# language it is present like Action and Func classes.
The answer to your question and semantic of Columns method something like this:

```
public ColumnCollection Columns(Func<ColumnCollection,ColumnCollection> columnCollectionFunc)
    => columnCollectionFunc(_someInternalColumnCollection);
```

Comment: I don't think it's `List<ColumnClass>` because `Add` seems to operate differently here.

Comment: That won't compile, it doesn't return anything (and `Action<T>` is probably wrong here too, as it represents a `void` method, you'll need to use `Func<T, TResult>` instead)

Comment: @Che Thank you for the example syntax. Add() is indeed different (as in it comes form a custom ColumnCollection object) and not straight form a list. Thank you

Comment: @lordvlad30 Just replace List<ColumnClass> to ColumnCollection then. I think it covers your case. I edited answer.